# What is the right approach to handle asynchronous task in compose (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state, viewmodel

As I am making progress in learning compose and Android in general. I need some help regarding best approach to handle async task.

lets say I have a button that call some methods of a view model

```
    // PRIMARY BUTTON
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 24.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 16.dp),
        onClick = {
            // STOP LOADING
            viewModel.triggerLoading()

            coroutineScope.launch {
                // GIVES A LITTLE DELAY OF 1000ms.
                viewModel.doTask()
                // STOP LOADING
                viewModel.triggerLoading()
                // CALLBACK TO PARENT ACTIVITY
                onSave.invoke(
                    Todo(
                        title = viewModel.state.value.title,
                        date = viewModel.state.value.date,
                        type = viewModel.state.value.category,
                        time = viewModel.state.value.time,
                        notes = viewModel.state.value.notes,
                        isChecked = false
                    )
                )
            }
        }) {
        Text(
            text = "Save", style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
        )
    }
```

the view model is as follows

```
    class AddTodoViewModel : ViewModel() {
        var state = mutableStateOf(AddTodoState())
    
        fun triggerLoading() {
            state.value = state.value.copy(loading = !state.value.loading)
        }
    
        suspend fun doTask() {
            delay(1000L)
        }
    }
    
    data class AddTodoState(
        var title: String = "",
        var notes: String = "",
        var date: String = "",
        var time: String = "",
        var category: Constants? = null,
        var loading: Boolean = false
    )
```

As you can see there is a `suspend` function that delay for **1sec**. My approach is working fine.

But what could be the best approach like how can I handle the loading and delay inside `viewModel` when button clicks only when delay completes then I want the `onPop` callback to be invoked.

**EIDT**
Here is the calling code

```
        AddTodo(viewModel = viewModel, onPop = {
                this.finish()
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
                    overrideActivityTransition(
                        OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,
                        R.anim.slide_out_top,
                        R.anim.slide_in_top
                    )
                } else {
                    overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_out_top,
                        R.anim.slide_in_top
                    )
                }
            }, onSave = { todo ->
                val gson = Gson()
                val intent = Intent().apply {
                    putExtra(
                        "model",
                        gson.toJson(todo)
                    )
                }
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
                this.finish()
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
                    overrideActivityTransition(
                        OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,
                        R.anim.slide_out_top,
                        R.anim.slide_in_top
                    )
                } else {
                    overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_out_top,
                        R.anim.slide_in_top
                    )
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see any `onPop` callback in your code. What should the `onPop` callback do?

Comment: ```onSave.invoke()``` is popping the current activity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Note that in Compose, you should only use one single Activity, so is there a reason why you want to use multiple Activities?

Comment: No specific reason just combining multiple activities and compose navigation in a single project.